# Second update is executed before the first

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA in a microservice architecture. I have a simple (actually it uses generics, but for the sake of simplicity, let's assume this is equivalent) save method in MyService, which is in a shared library between the two applications:

```
@SneakyThrows
@Transactional
public DTO save(DTO dto) {
    MyEntity entity = Optional
        .ofNullable(dto.getId())
        .flatMap(repository::findById)
        .orElse(new MyEntity());
    modelMapper.map(dto, entity);
    return modelMapper.map(repository.save(entity), DTO.class);
}
```

where repository is a JpaRepository. So far, so good. I have two Spring applications; the application A does some stuff, saves an entity and then calls application B, in the following manner:

```
DTO dto = myService.findById(id);
//modifying the dto...
myService.save(dto);
myFeignClient.callApplicationB(id);
```

The structure behind the application B is similar (find, edit, save), yet logging a trace on the db (I use SQL Server, 2016 or 2019 behave the same) I see that the second update (the one by the application B) is executed before the "first" one (the one by the application A). Am I missing a obvious configuration or should I search the issue elsewhere?

Comment: What are you using to log traces? Could the logging in Application A only flush periodically?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I use SQL Server Profiler to log traces. Will check the flush config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the following [@Transactional pitfall](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth#transactional-pitfalls): the service which used the save method was annotated with `@Transactional`, so all the methods where transactional, like in the following snippet

```
@Transactional
void myMethod(Long id) {
    DTO dto = myService.findById(id);
    //modifying the dto...
    myService.save(dto);
    myFeignClient.callApplicationB(id);
}
```

I changed the code in the following way

```
void myMethod(Long id) {
    myTransactionalMethod(id);
    myFeignClient.callApplicationB(id);
}


@Transactional
void myTransactionalMethod(Long id) {
    DTO dto = myService.findById(id);
    //modifying the dto...
    myService.save(dto);
}
```

Another solution, if one wants to keep the same transactional boundaries, is to pass the whole dto to the application B, and return it modified:

```
@Transactional
void myMethod(Long id) {
    DTO dto = myService.findById(id);
    //modifying the dto...
    dto = myFeignClient.callApplicationB(dto);
    myService.save(dto);
}
```

EDIT: I will try to clarify the logic behind the transactions. The old logic was the following:

- application A opens a (physical) transactions A1 and edits the dto;
- application A opens a (logical) transaction A2 inside the transaction A1 and saves the dto;
- application A closes the transaction A2: the edits are not committed to db as the A1 transaction is still open;
- application A calls application B;
- application B opens a (physical) transactions B1 and edits the dto;
- application B opens a (logical) transaction B2 inside the transaction B1 and saves the dto;
- application B closes the transaction B2;
- application B replies to application A and closes the transaction B1: the changes made by B are committed to db;
- application A receives the response and closes the transaction A1: the changes made by A overwrite the changes made by B.

In the solution, the transaction A1 is closed before the call to application B, so the changes made by A are committed before any change made by B.

Comment: OP memtioned about two separate spring application. In that case above mentioned solution won’t work. In that case OP have to use inter service like solutions.

Comment: @RatulSharker I am OP... I will clarify the logic behind the problem in the question.